# Create a new class definition with different default arguments, using some other class definition?

Tags: python, class

Say I have the following class in Python 2.7:

```
class X():
    def __init__(self, alpha=1):
        self.alpha = alpha
        print self.alpha

    def beta(self, gamma=1):
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.omega = self.alpha + self.gamma
        print self.omega
```

I want to use the class definition to create another class definition with different default arguments, e.g. something like:

```
Y = f(X, alpha=2, gamma=2)
```

or

```
Y = f(X, __init__.alpha=2, beta.gamma=2)
```

which should be equivalent to:

```
class Y():
    def __init__(self, alpha=2):
        self.alpha = alpha
        print self.alpha

    def beta(self, gamma=2):
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.omega = self.alpha + self.gamma
        print self.omega
```

Is it possible to do something like this in Python 2.7 (or 3?)?

(I know you can use the `functools.partial` to do the equivalent for functions; so I was wondering if there was anything similar for classes)

Comment: Do you really need another class? You could write a factory function that created instances of a common class, but with different defaults.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function that creates classes for you:

```
def makeclass(alpha, gamma):
    class C():
        def __init__(self, alpha=alpha):
            self.alpha = alpha
            print self.alpha

        def beta(self, gamma=gamma):
            self.gamma = gamma
            self.omega = self.alpha + self.gamma
            print self.omega

    return C
```

```
>>> X = makeclass(1, 1)
>>> Y = makeclass(2, 2)
>>> x = X() # X is the class, x is an instance
1
>>> x.beta()
2
>>> y = Y()
2
>>> y.beta()
4
```

Answer (score 0):

This *can* be done, but it's a bit messy.

This code:

```
class Foo(base1, base2, ...):
    bar = something
    baz = something_else
    def qux(self):
        ...
```

...is equivalent to this code, though I'm not sure this is correct if `Foo` is a classic class:

```
Foo = type('Foo', (base1, base2, ...), {'bar': something, 'baz': something_else,
                                        'qux': lambda self: ...})
```

So we can create classes on the fly, and attach custom method objects to them.

For your specific case, we need to make these calls (assuming you convert X into a new-style class by inheriting from `object`).  First, we extract methods from X and apply `functools.partial`:

```
new_init = functools.partial(X.__init__.im_func, # Just X.__init__ in 3.x
                             alpha=2)
new_beta = functools.partial(X.beta.im_func, # Just X.beta in 3.x
                             gamma=2)
```

The `im_func` attribute grabs the underlying function out of the unbound method object.  In Python 3, there's no such thing as an unbound method, so we don't need to use this attribute; `X.__init__` is just the function itself.

Next, we create the class:

```
Y = type('Y', (object,), {'__init__': new_init, 'beta': new_beta})
```

Unfortunately, we don't have any reasonable way of getting a list of the functions we need to redefine here.  If we use `dir()` we'll get a lot of irrelevant special attributes.  We could use the class's `__dict__`, but that won't include any inherited methods.  I think we may need to search `X.__mro__` for a fully correct listing of methods:

```
result = {}
for class_ in X.__mro__:
    for name, value in class_.__dict__.items():
        if name not in result:
            result[name] = value
```

We also need to figure out which arguments to override in each case; [`inspect.getargspec()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) is a good starting point for this, but it will not help much if any of the methods are variadic (i.e. if they take `*args` or `**kwargs` arguments).